# Absolute positioned div forgets container and flows out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a container which is set to `float:none` and `margin:0 auto;` and `width:80%;` But one of the div, which is absolutely positioned inside the container, flows out of the container.

The code is

```
    <main>
       <div class="container">
          <div class="main_top"></div>
          <div class="main_bottom"></div>
       </div>
    </main>
```

and the css is

```
    .container {
        float: none;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
       }
    main { 
       float:left; 
       position:relative;
      }
    .main_top {
       float: left;
       width: 100%;
     }
    .main-bottom {
       position:absolute;
       width:100%;
     }
```

now the `.main-bottom` flows out of the `.container` width. As this is a responsive Website, Without that it is impossible to achieve responsiveness. Please Help.

Please check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=VptJurBM6I) for more details.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: absolutely positioned elements go out of the normal document flow that's why...

Comment: the absolute positioned flows out because it orientates itself to the next relative element. and that is the main not the container

Comment: Define .container{position:relative;}

Comment: .container {position:relative;} will make it worse as it is not floated and no height defined; that took .main-bottom to top of the document just below the header against to the actual position near footer where it is supposed to reside.

Comment: can you show your issue in a fiddle? check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3pp0wx0k/ I could not find any problem.

Comment: Please check this [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=VptJurBM6I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.container{
position:releative;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

you have to define parent relative to bind absolute child

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x4wpvvLs/)

Comment: @CodeName44 if the answer is correct please accept it so it will help others

Comment: you have to give height to container

Comment: by giving main top position relative and setting height of container and making main bottom {bottom:0;}

Answer (score 0):

When you position an element (relative, fixed or absolute) its reference is the first positioned parent element. So you need to tell the element that it has to be positioned after the container:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Be careful with mixing floats and positioned elements, use a proper clearfix so the container dimensions are accurate.